# Using Picture box zoomin and zoomout in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am loading Picture Box. How can we zoom in and zoom out image in picture box? Is there any solution in vb.net?

Here is the code for loading image:

```
 PictureBox1.Load(D:\test.jpg)
 PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage` is correct. This value causes the image to stretch or shrink to fit the `PictureBox`, so you can change `PictureBox.Size` to zoom in or zoom out.

You can use `PictureBoxSizeMode.Autosize` to restore original size because this value causes the control to resize to always fit the image.

So you can create three `Button`:

1. zoom in: set `PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage` and increase `PictureBox.Size`
2. zoom out: set `PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage` and decrease `PictureBox.Size`
3. restore original size: set `PictureBoxSizeMode.Autosize`

To increase/decrease `PictureBox.Size` you can multiply its current `Height`/`Width` to 1.1 (increase) or 0.9 (decrease).

Comment: ya thank you for your feedback. But i want to zoomin and zoomout option to view characters

Comment: Zoom In and Zoom Out must be done inside picture box, Is there any solution for this.